# How to center a submit button

Tags: html, css

Making a contact form with css and html.  Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto
```

to get my submit button centered.  Here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/T7UtM/

Comment: Why did you use a table for the button rather than a div like the rest.

Comment: That markup made a unicorn cry.

Comment: If you don't use a table, then it centers: http://jsfiddle.net/T7UtM/1/.  If you have to use a table (for whatever reason) you need your `margin: auto` on the table.

Answer (score 1):

In your case this will center the button:

```
.ss-item.ss-navigate{
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7UtM/2/

However **please** try to revise your markup, it's wrong on too many levels.